# libVLC Zoom and Pan

Tags: java, android, libvlc, vlc-android

There is method in MediaPlayer class named **setScale** which can be used for zooming which can be implemented for example inside pinch gesture, but the center of zooming is center of view. so the details in the sides of image can not be shown. 
So is there a capability of changing center of zoom or changeing the location of visible windows(pan the visible part of frames) in libVLC ?

**Edit :**
There is also `updateViewpoint(float yaw, float pitch, float roll, float fov, boolean absolute)`

but nothing changed when is scale the video and try to do :
`updateViewpoint(5f,0f,0f,0f,false);`

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know about java but using python, I resorted to using `video_set_crop_geometry(self, psz_geometry)` to enable zoom and pan features.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `--zoom` CLI option to your libvlc object which handles libvlc options (don't know which wrapper you're using, but they should expose this).

See https://superuser.com/a/129642

> There is also `updateViewpoint(float yaw, float pitch, float roll, float fov, boolean absolute)`

I believe this call *only* applies to 360 videos.